# Is there a recent (2013) guide for developing Audio Units in Mac OS X Mountain Lion?

Tags: core-audio, audiounit

I am working on developing some Audio Units. I am wondering if there exists a "getting started" guide that is more up-to-date than this one on Apple's website from 2007?:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioUnitProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

If not, can anyone recommend a good book for this?

I seem to already have a handle on it, but I would like to make sure that I am following the correct standards and a simple tutorial would be helpful for me to double-check that what I am doing is correct.

I am actually surprised that a simple google did not come up with much recent information on the development of audio units. I would appreciate if anybody could point me in the direction of information on this.

Thanks!

Comment: While I've not built any Audio Units on OS X I believe that reference is still current. i.e. Core Audio, at its, um, core, hasn't changed materially. Adamson's "Learning Core Audio" is also a great reference.

Answer (score 4):

Sadly, apple seems to be slowly abandoning AudioUnits. Most of their documentation is dead and the SDK won't even work out of the box on modern Mac systems without some modifications.

That said, I can also recommend "Learning CoreAudio".

Comment: +1 …but i wouldn't consider them abandoning AUs. rather, developing other technologies (i.e. more user-friendly, higher level abstractions) wrt the APIs they are pushing out. setting up a new AU project which correctly loads and validates has always required a 750 of vodka -- the docs have always been neglected and the samples/CAPublic are generally behind. if it's true, what would replace AUs?

Comment: AudioUnits, ACCodecs, AudioFile subclasses- the list goes on.  It's sad to see Core Audio neglected.

Comment: I've already found Learning CoreAudio to be lacking with current (OS X Yosemite) and Xcode setups, and left hanging with errors even on the first example.